# How to show UIImageView Quick Look by address?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, xcode5

In Xcode 5, we can now hover over a UIImageView variable to get a Quick Look of the image.  If I want to see the image of an image view whose variable I don't have direct access to, but I have the hex address, is there a way to show it?  i.e., If I know there's a UIImageView at `0x12193fb0`, doing `po 0x12193fb0` in the debugger will print out the info about the object.  Is there a similar way to Quick Look by address?  Using the Variables View next to the debugger isn't an option, since I'm breaking the program manually, so it's not in the context of the object that owns the image view.

Comment: When apple announced this feature for XCode5 in WWDC, they only mentioned doing it through XCode... not through the debugger interface. I couldn't find any information about this on their developer page either which makes me answer your question by saying NO, sorry you are out of luck.

Comment: Can you dump the memory starting at that location and ending at the usual "end" pattern for the filetype in question and then just save is a a png or jpg or whatever? I can't see there being a way to have Xcode interpret that address as an image and feed it into its quick look doodad.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a watch for your variable (Debug area, variables view). You just have to cast it if you only have the pointer address. Eg.

```
(NSString*)0x1234567
```

The watch can be added from the context menu.

#### Quick update:

Just to clarify myself, you can get to the following just by knowing the address. In this instance I just typed `(BNMap*)0xb4b5dd0` as the expression.

[image: Quick Expression]

Comment: sorry, maybe i wasn't clear from the title before, but I'm looking for a way to Quick Look it.

Comment: I don't think that's possible to open up the same quick look dialog without a variable, but you can add variables as a watch and browse them that way. They don't have to be in the same context. Also, there's an option to "Show in All Stack Frames". If just you need to browse the object graph, I think this is the only way. It works anywere though.